# Issue when testing ngrx effects with jest and jasmine-marbles

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects, jasmine-marbles

I'm using `jest` and `jasmine-marbles` to test my `ngrx-effects`. So far so good, but I have a special case where I need to use `withLatestFrom` to access the `Store` inside an effect like this:

```
@Effect()
createDataSourceSuccess$ = this.actions$
  .ofType<sourceActions.CreateDataSourceSuccess>(
    sourceActions.DataSourceActionTypes.CreateDataSourceSuccess
  )
  .pipe(
    map(action => action.dataSource),
    withLatestFrom(this.store.select(getSourceUploadProgress)),
    switchMap(([source, progress]: [DataSource, UploadProgress]) =>
     of(
        new sourceActions.StartSourceUploadProgress({
          id: source.fileId,
          uploadProgress: progress,
        })
      )
    )
  );
```

Also I did set up my test like this:

```
it('should return StartSourceUploadProgress for CreateDataSourceSuccess', () => {
  const dataSource = dataSources[0];
  const action = new dataSourceActions.CreateDataSourceSuccess(dataSource);
  const outcome = new dataSourceActions.StartSourceUploadProgress({
    id: dataSource.fileId,
    uploadProgress: null,
  });

  store.select = jest.fn(_selector => of(null));

  actions.stream = hot('-a-', { a: action });
  const expected = cold('--b', { b: outcome });

  expect(effects.createDataSourceSuccess$).toBeObservable(expected);
});
```

I'd also note that I successfully set up mocks for the `Store` and for the `Actions` as all other tests work fine. The only difference between this and the others is that the `Store` and `withLatestFrom` is not present in those effects.

Finally this is the error output I get:

```
 DataSourceEffects › should return StartSourceUploadProgress for CreateDataSourceSuccess

    TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

This solution work for me

```
it('should return StartSourceUploadProgress for CreateDataSourceSuccess', () => {
  const dataSource = dataSources[0];
  const action = new dataSourceActions.CreateDataSourceSuccess(dataSource);
  const outcome = new dataSourceActions.StartSourceUploadProgress({
    id: dataSource.fileId,
    uploadProgress: null,
  });

  actions.stream = hot('-a-', { a: action });
  const expected = cold('--b', { b: outcome });

  store.select = jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(() => of(new SourceUploadProgress()));

  expect(effects.createDataSourceSuccess$).toBeObservable(expected);
});
```

Comment: Exactly what is the proposed solution? I changed `jest.fn(_selector => of(null))` to `jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(() => of(null))` but still getting the same error.

Comment: Try to use `cold` in mockImpl.  `jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(() => cold('a', {a: null}))`

Comment: It's not working for me. It seems like the effect is failing to get the action stream because of some underlying error.